# Check if uid numbers in /etc/passwd are in a certain range and not already used, with nested ifs

Tags: bash, shell, nested-if

I am trying to check the uid's that are already used and in within a range from 1000 to 60000, with nested if conditions but only the range condition works.
Also it prints the $hpass content.
Any ideas how to improve the code?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbpasswd=$(cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f3 | sort -n)
hpass=$(printf '%d\n' "$dbpasswd")  #to put all numbers on separeate line
while true; do
read -p "Enter a number between 1000 and 59999" num
echo ""
if [[ "$num" -gt 1000 && "$num" -lt 60000 ]]; then
   if [[ "$num" -eq "$hpass" ]]; then 
   echo "$num is already in use"
   else
   echo "$num is in range and not yet used!"
   break
   fi
else
   echo "$num is out of range"
fi
done
```

Comment: Please add a valid shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

Comment: I would validate the number to be in range, but then use `grep -q $input /etc/password` to see if the number is already in use (maybe `awk` focusing on the particular `$1...$9` field used). Good luck.

Comment: On modern systems, checking the status of `getent passwd "$uid"` is a *much* more reliable way of finding if a UID is already used than scanning '/etc/passwd'.

Comment: Looks like you might be missing a double quote in this line: `if [[ "$num -eq "$hpass" ]]; then`

Comment: @j_b yes, missed double quote, edited , thanks

Comment: `$dbpasswd` will contain a *list* of UID numbers, not just a single number, so trying to print it with `%d` format will fail (and is also unnecessary, since it's already in one-entry-per-line format). Similarly, `-eq` is to test for equality between two individual numbers, not for membership in a list of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Load the list of `/etc/passwd` uids into an array:

```
uids=()

while read -r uid
do
    uids[$uid]="$uid"
done < <(cut -d":" -f3 /etc/passwd)
```

Modifying OP's current code to test if `$num` is an element in the array:

```
while true; do
    read -p "Enter a number between 1000 and 59999: " num
    echo ""

    if [[ "$num" -gt 1000 && "$num" -lt 60000 ]]; then
        if [[ -n "${uids[num]}" ]]; then 
            echo "$num is already in use"
        else
            echo "$num is in range and not yet used!"
            break
        fi
    else
        echo "$num is out of range"
    fi
done
```